# jQuery How to get the selected value of the radiobutton with set select group?

Tags: jquery

I have that inputs:

```
<input type="radio" name='lang' value='3' />
<input type="radio" name='lang' value='4' />
```

I try to get the value of the selected radio button. To do so, I'm using the code

> $('input[name="lang"]').val()

but it always returns `3`. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always returns "3" because it returns the first it finds.

To get the checked one, use:

```
$('input[name="lang"]:checked').val()
```